# Creating a number of pandas dataframes from a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file of football stats and I would like to calculate running averages for certain key stats. The only way I can think to do it is to create a pandas dataframe for each team, do the calculation and then add the info back into the original dataframe. Here I want to run through the list of teams and create a dataframe for each. Can I do this? Here's what I have:

```
teamlist = []
for x in df['team1']:
    if x not in teamlist:
        teamlist.append(x)
#here's what I would use to create 1 dataframe
arsenal = df.loc[df['team1']=='Arsenal']

for x in teamlist:
    something  = df.loc[df['team1']== x]
```

Where I have 'something' I would like to have 'H' + x + 'df'
so that the dataframe would be called HArsenaldf for example.

Also, if there is an easier way to calculate moving averages for only certain rows in a dataframe, that would be great.

Comment: well, not a good idea for creating a multiple dataframes, you can create a single daraframe and create the function where you can apply the moving average and then pass your data through this code `df.groupby('column_name').apply(lambda x: yourfuncationanmehere(x))`

where x will access your all data columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [expanding](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html#pandas.DataFrame.expanding) transformation, as shown in the example below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Team': list('AAAAABBB'),
                   'Score': range(1,9)})


df['RunningAvg'] = df.groupby('Team')['Score'].transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean())

df

#   Score Team  RunningAvg
#0      1    A         1.0
#1      2    A         1.5
#2      3    A         2.0
#3      4    A         2.5
#4      5    A         3.0
#5      6    B         6.0
#6      7    B         6.5
#7      8    B         7.0
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for your comments. Firstly when I run this I get this error: AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'mean'.  Secondly, I forgot to mention I am trying to do a 5 point moving average.

Comment: I think I have sorted it out now using (lambda x: x.rolling(5).mean()).

Comment: @Buck_Shot Sure, but that `5` in `rolling()` is a window and I thought you don't want windowed mean but an ongoing, `expanding`,  one. It would've been much easier with that detail :)